# What does this `cat` statement do?

Tags: shell-script, cat, here-document

I'm trying to figure out what this statement in a Bash file does. I think it combines `stdout`, `stderr` and output it to the file `$log` is pointing to and append the multiline string to it. Is it right?

```
cat << EOF >> $log 2>&1   
the quick brown  
fox jumps  
EOF
```

Comment: Type man bash, and read up on it. None if the stuff after `cat` is an input to `cat`, it is interpreted by bash before `cat` is started. On Unix much stuff is done by the shell not the commands. This makes things simpler to write and more consistent to use.

Comment: it does the same thing every `cat` statement does - it concatenates `stdin` to `stdout`.

Comment: The title is undescriptive, but I can't think of a good summary either, mostly because it's unclear what exactly about the command is confusing. Maybe something like "What does a pair of less-than-signs mean in bash?" would work.

Answer (score 7):

First, `cat` must be written lowercase. This command statement uses the concept of [here documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

**The first part** `cat << EOF` means that `stdin` (standard input) of the command comes afterwards. All that comes after the first line until the word `EOF` is the standard input to the command `cat`. Or from the documentation:

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only **delimiter** (in your case it's *EOF*) (with no
>   trailing blanks) is seen.  All  of  the  lines read up to that point
>   are then used as the standard input for a command.

**The second part** of the command `>> $log 2>&1` means that the output of `stdout` and `stderr` both, should be appended to a file whose name is in the variable `$log`.

**Conclusion:** A file like this is now generated:

```
the quick brown
fox jumps
```